# Electron Cash wallet password not working!

Tags: bitcoin-cash, wallet-recovery, electron-cash

I downloaded the wallet software from electroncash.org, version 2.9.4. I then transferred some Bitcoins from Coinbase using shapeshift to my new BCH wallet and after a few minutes, saw my tokens alright.

Then 2 days later, when I fired up the software again, my password didn't work!

Can you help me? I got the seed phrase but how do i use it?
When I fire up the software, the only wallet to choose is **default_wallet**. I also see the password field just below the pull down menu to select my wallet. I also tried entering the seed phrase into the password field.

Comment: I guess you transferred BCH to your BCH wallet?  Not bitcoins hopefully.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Electron Cash Wallet now suddenly not accepting password?](/questions/59804/electron-cash-wallet-now-suddenly-not-accepting-password)

Comment: FOUND A SOLUTION!!!!  Once the software is loaded, you just create a new wallet. You do this by entering a new name in the field. Then it will ask you to create a new wallet. You just enter your seed phrase once prompted and BOOM, your tokens appear YAHOOO!

Comment: @Andre: Could you please post this as an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the caps locks on. For me it was that the application wasn't telling me that my caps lock was on. Then, on restart, "Wrong password." Etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, and found a solution. If you a open new wallet by importing your private keys (and import only adresses without keys,) then you will get read-only wallet, so on another PC I opened another wallet, imported private keys only, not adresses, and didn't encrypt it with password, then the wallet started to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you help me? I got the seed phrase but how do i use it? When I fire up the software, the only wallet to choose is default_wallet.

Type in a unique filename instead of default_wallet. Say wallet-restoration-62907. Then click next and choose 'standard wallet' and next again and then 'i already have a seed'. Continue as per on-screen instructions to restore from seed.